# how to loop table row and get the column checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Using ajax, how to:

1. loop through each table row
2. get the respective column checkbox value
3. upon finish loop, store in database (refer to **Database** section below)

**javascript/jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnUpdPermission').on('click', function(e) {
            var id = '<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>';

            $('#table_perm tbody tr').each(function(){

            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="table_perm">
        <thead>
            <th>Permission</th>
            <th>Read</th>
            <th>Create</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="r[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="c[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="e[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="d[]"/></td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Invoice</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="r[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="c[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="e[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="d[]"/></td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quotation</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="r[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="c[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="e[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="d[]"/></td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Banking</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="r[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="c[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="e[]"/></td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="d[]"/></td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdPermission">Save</button>
```

**HTML (screenshot)**
[image]

**Database table design**
[image]

1. **file_id** is the foreign key to the file master table (page that authorized user will access)
2. **user_id** is the foreign key to the user master table (to whom this access is granted)
3. **rights** r=read,c=create,e=edit,d=delete

Comment: Limit your question.

Comment: That is why I put points form because they are closely related so that I wont create more questions just for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it well, each row corresponds to permissions to one file master table, right? (identified by `file_id` in your database) If that's the case, first I'd put that id each table row (as an id, as a data-* field, etc.)...

```
<tr data-id="3">
    <td>Product</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="r[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="c[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="e[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="d[]"/></td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="4">
    <td>Invoice</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="r[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="c[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="e[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="d[]"/></td>
</tr>
...................
```

Then, considering your table structure, to loop your rows and get all the checkboxes values, one option could be...

```
var myPermissions = {};

$('#table_perm tbody tr').each(function() {

    var sectionId = $(this).data('id');
    var sectionPermissions = [];

    $(this).find('input.big-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        sectionPermissions.push($(this).attr('name').charAt(0));
    });

    myPermissions[sectionId] = sectionPermissions.join(',');

});
```

So you finally get an object `myPermissions` with all permissions for each section...

```
{
    3: "r,c",
    4: "r,d",
    5: "c,e,d"
    ....
}
```

You can send that in your ajax call as a parameter.

**NOTE**: Two pieces of advice in your code...

1. There's an error in your html, your closing td lines twice (`</td></td>`)
2. If you're going to do this collecting data with ajax and not using a form, to avoid getting the permission letter from the string name, it would be better if you assign a value to each checkbox indicating the letter of that permission. I mean...

   ```
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="r[]" value="r"/></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" name="c[]" value="c"/></td>
   ..........
   ```

   ... so then would be easier and cleaner to get the value...

   ```
   sectionPermissions.push($(this).val());
   ```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your advice and pointing the duplicate `</td>` out. For your NOTE: 2, can I remove the `name="[]"` ? It seems useless since we are using `value=""`

Answer (score 2):

> 1.loop through each table row

You should use `.each` method in combination with `children`.

**children method gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.**

```
$('#table_perm tbody tr').each(function(){
      $(this).children('td').each(function(){

      });
});
```

> 2.get the respective column checkbox value

For this you can use `find` method.

```
$('#table_perm tbody tr').each(function(){
      $(this).children('td').each(function(){
         let checkboxValue = $(this).find('.big-checkbox').val();
      });
});
```

> 3.upon finish loop, store in database

For this, you can create an **asynchronous** call by sending all the information via AJAX or you can use a `form` by passing an action method from server-side.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I think I am missing something here. Is it I need to set each row checkbox name unique? If not how does the logic knows which *read* rights is given to which page? Right?

Comment: @4LeaveCover, you can pass a binary array from each page like [1,0,0,1].`1` means that has access and `0` not.